# Limit of $(x+1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2 +1})$ as $x\to-\infty$

Tags: limits, solution-verification

This seemed easy at first, but then I confronted my result with the one I got from WolframAlpha and they are different:

$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}(x+1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2 +1})
$$

WolframAlpha says the limit is equal to 0, though for me it seems to be negative infinity. I tried some simple algebraic manipulation, namely multiplying each factor by 1:

$$
\frac{x\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}+\frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}+[(x+1)^2+1]*\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}
$$

The last part is 0, because the fraction goes to 0:

$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}([(x+1)^2+1]*\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}})=0
$$

The middle part is 1 and the first part should be negative infinity, as the only factor left standing is x and it goes to negative infinity. What am I missing?

Comment: hint: let (x+1) be "a".

Comment: @LEO, damn, so the +1 factor under the square root becomes irrelevant and the whole limit effectively becomes $a-a = 0$. That's what you're sayin'? :D

Comment: The last part does not converge to 0. $(x+1)^2$ converges to infinity and the fraction is just equal to $\sqrt{(x+1)^2 + 1}$, which therefore goes to infinity. The expansion of the fractions is pointless, I think.

Comment: @MarekM. my hint is just for becoming multiplication with conjugate easy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time when you want to get rid of a root expression you use the 3rd binomial formula. So you would expand into a fraction with $(x+1-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1})$

So we get:

$\frac{(x+1)^2-(x+1)^2-1}{x+1-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}=\frac{-1}{x+1-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}-(x+1)}$

We have $\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}-(x+1)\to\infty$ as $x\to -\infty$. So the fraction goes to $0$.

Comment: There's actually a plus sign between the $x+1$ and the square root. But anyway, I don't think I get your solution :(

Comment: @MarekM. it is multiplied by conjugate .

Comment: @MarekM. The main point of the solution is to use the 3rd binomial formula. 
Namely $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$, so we get rid of the root. It is not that different from your approach. We just have $\frac{(x+1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1})(x+1-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1})}{(x+1)-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}$

Comment: After a good night sleep, this looks right. Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't like limits at $-\infty$. I'd rewrite it as
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(1-x+\sqrt{1+(x-1)^2}\right)
=\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(-y+\sqrt{1+y^2}\right)$$
(setting $y=x-1$). Then
$$-y+\sqrt{1+y^2}=\frac{-y^2+(1+y^2)}{y+\sqrt{1+y^2}}
=\frac{1}{y+\sqrt{1+y^2}}\to0$$
as $y\to\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was in writing $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\frac{(x+1)^2+1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}=0$. The expression $\frac{(x+1)^2+1}{\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}}$ equals $\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}$, which tends to $\infty$ as $x\rightarrow-\infty$.

You can attack this problem using other techniques. One approach is to multiply and divide by the conjugate of $x+1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}$, namely $x+1-\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}$, then use the difference of squares formula to simplify the result. Alternatively, if you are comfortable with hyperbolic functions and the exponential function $e^x$, you could write

$$x+1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}=e^{\sinh ^{-1}(x+1)}$$

and use the fact that $\lim_{x\to -\infty}\sinh ^{-1}(x)=-\infty$ (this limit can be proven without using the logarithmic form of $\sinh ^{-1}x$). Since $\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^x=0$, we have that

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}e^{\sinh ^{-1}(x+1)}=0$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(x+1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2+1}\right)=0$$.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(x+1+\sqrt{(x+1)^2 +1}\right)
$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(x+1+|x+1|\sqrt{1+\dfrac1{(x+1)^2}}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(x+1+|x+1|\left[1+\frac1{2(x+1)^2}\cdots\right]\right)$$

$$=\lim_{x\to-\infty}\left(x+1-(x+1)-(x+1)\left[\frac1{2(x+1)^2}\cdots\right]\right)=0.$$

Comment: I don't understand where the second "line" in your solution comes from, namely the 1/2.

Comment: Binomial expansion $(1+y)^n=1+ny\cdots$ with $n=1/2$